# Selecting elements with lodash where inner properties match values in an array

Tags: typescript, lodash

I currently have the following and want to know if there is a cleaner way to do it since I do not like the inclusion of the flag.

```
const countries = [...];
const religionFilter = [ "religA", "religB" ];
const religionFilteredCountries = [];

_.forEach(countries,
    c => {
        let flag = false;

        _.forEach(c.info, i => {
            if (_.includes(religionFilter, i.religions)) {
                flag = true;
            }
        });
        if (flag) {
            religionFilteredCountries.push(c);
        }
    }
);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/3wsny0r2/740).

---

Here is the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wsny0r2/761/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using lodash, you can write `religionFilteredCountries` like this:

```
const religionFilteredCountries =
  countries.filter((c) => _.intersection(religionFilter, c.religions).length > 0);
```

Comment: I've updated my question as it seems I pasted the wrong model into the first jsfiddle. Any chance you could also update your answer? I also seem to be getting an error, at least in jsfiddle, with that particular code snippet unless I switch from typescript to javascript.

Comment: The code in the fiddle was the same as in the question text, but if you update the question, I can adapt the answer. Otherwise the answer won't make any sense. The error seems some jsfiddle quirk, which can be fixed by adding an explicit return to the arrow function`(c) => {return ..}`, but this is not necessary in normal TypeScript.

Comment: Actually it's probably easier to leave the question as is and replace `c.religions` with `_.map(c.info, 'religion')` to get it working in your second fiddle.