# How to select elements with lodash where inner properties match values in different array

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076600/selecting-elements-with-lodash-where-inner-properties-match-values-in-an-array) question except multiple properties are being evaluated against different arrays.

I have the following foreach loops and flags which perform the desired function.

```
var countries = [...];
var religionFilter = ["religA", "religB"];
var believersFilter = ["many"];
var religionFilteredCountries = [];

_.forEach(countries,
    c => {
    let flag = false;
    _.forEach(c.info, i => {
        if (_.includes(religionFilter, i.religion) && _.includes(believersFilter, i.believers)) {
            flag = true;
        }
    });
    if (flag) {
        religionFilteredCountries.push(c);
    }
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3wsny0r2/807/).

The question is how to convert this code to a minimal lodash filter.

Comment: I don't see a question. Also, please make use of StackOverflow's snippet functionality instead of external code representation.

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Ele the example in jsfiddle is very clearly a minimal, complete and verifiable example. I am not sure what else you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish that using ES6:

```
var religionFilteredCountries = countries.filter(c => c.info.find(i => religionFilter.includes(i.religion) && believersFilter.includes(i.believers)));
```

Using Lodash it should be very similar:

```
var religionFilteredCountries = _.filter(countries, c => _.find(c.info, i => _.includes(religionFilter, i.religion) && _.includes(believersFilter, i.believers)));
```